# I want to replace backlashes in python, replacing \\ by \ in a byte sequence

Tags: python, replace, byte, encode

So I have a byte sequence that looks like this:

```
key = b"b')F\\x87\\x86\\xfc~Z\\xaa\\x15pf}\\xe6\\x9f\\xf5\\xd0' "
```

and I want it to look like this: `b')F\x87\x86\xfc~Z\xaa\x15pf}\xe6\x9f\xf5\xd0'`

I am manipulating the sequence in bytes and not converting it in string because I need it the sequence to remain in byte type, when I `decode()` it and `encode()` it again the format changes and using the `.replace` method is pointless so working with the replace method on the byte sequence is what I have found to be most practical...except for the backlashes.

I use the replace method to manipulate the byte sequence so it looks the way i want it with the following code:

```
modified_bytes = key.replace(b"b'", b"").replace(b"'", b"").replace(b' ', b'').replace(b'\\\\',b'\\')
```

When I print it, it gives me
`b')F\\x87\\x86\\xfc~Z\\xaa\\x15pf}\\xe6\\x9f\\xf5\\xd0'`

which is almost the result I am looking for..Except for the backlashes, I am stuck and I cannot get rid of them even with the `.replace(b'\\\\',b'\\')` , is it even possible?

Comment: How exactly did you get this byte sequence in the first place? The code for that source is probably broken; there is probably not a good reason for it to give you this kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `raw_unicode_escape` to escape backslashes

```
key.replace(b"b'", b"").replace(b"' ", b"").decode('unicode_escape').encode("raw_unicode_escape")
```